# Find inverse of an operator and its norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I have an operator $A\in {B(L^2[0,1])}$ and $(Ax)(t) = x(t) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x(s)ds$ where
$L_2[0,1]$ [is a space](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lp_spaces) of functions for which the 2th power of their absolute value is Lebesgue integrable
$B(L^2[0,1])$ - [Banach algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra)

I need to find norm of my inverse operator in order to find distance to the set of non-invertible operators.
My attempt:

1. I found $A^{-1}$. $A: x(t) \mapsto x(t)-1/2\int_{0}^{1}x(s)ds = y(t)$ Hence, $(A^{-1}y)(t) = y(t) - e^{t}\int_{0}^{1}e^sy(s)ds$.     $\left\| (A^{-1}y)(t)\right\| = (\int_{0}^{1}\left|y(t)-e^{t}\int_{0}^{1}e^sy(s)ds \right|^2dt)^{1/2}$. But I understand that in $L_2[0,1]$ space it is hard to solve it. It will be easier if our space was continuous functions.
2. So, my second idea is to use Fourier series to transform my function: $x(t)-1/2\int_{0}^{1}x(s)ds$. So it will be easier. Or maybe not

Pls, can someone help? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how $y(t)-e^t\int_0^1e^sy(s)\mathrm{d}s$ is bounded, let alone square integrable. It seems your inverse is a bit off. For a different one, note that $\int_0^1 (Ax)(s)\mathrm{d}s = \int^1_0 x(s)\mathrm{d}s-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1x(s)\mathrm{d}s=\frac 12\int_0^1x(s)\mathrm{d}s$, so $(A^{-1}y)(t) = y(t) + \int_0^1 y(s)\mathrm{d}(s)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $A^{-1}$ you calculated is wrong. In fact, the inverse operator is given by
$$(A^{-1}y)(t)=y(t)+\int_0^1 y(s)\,ds$$
To see this, denote the integral $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt$ by $\overline{f}$. Then
$$Ax=x-\frac{1}{2}\overline{x}$$
If $y=Ax$, then
$$\overline{y}=\overline{Ax}=\overline{x}-\frac{1}{2}\overline{x}=\frac{1}{2}\overline{x}$$
hence if $y=Ax$ then
$$y=x-\overline{y}$$
and so
$$x=y+\overline{y}$$
so the inverse operator is given by
$$(A^{-1}y)(t)=y(t)+\int_0^1y(s)\,ds$$
The calculation of the norm of the inverse is then straight-forward. First we note that by the triangle inequality
$$\|A^{-1}y\|=\|y+\overline{y}\|\leq \|y\|+\|\overline{y}\|=\|y\|+|\overline{y}|\qquad (1)$$
and by the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality,
$$|\overline{y}|=\left |\int_0^1y(s)\,ds\right|\leq \left(\int_0^1 |y(s)|^2\,ds\right)^{1/2}=\|y\|$$
Hence, by (1)
$$\|A^{-1}y\|\leq 2\|y\|$$
which implies that
$$\|A^{-1}\|\leq 2$$
Take the constant function $y_0\equiv 1$, which has norm $1$, and
$$\|A^{-1}y_0\|=2=2\|y_0\|$$
which proves that in fact,
$$\|A^{-1}\|=2$$

Answer (score 2):

The operator is of the form $$A=I-{1\over 2}P=(I-P)+{1\over 2}P$$ where $P$ is a nontrivial orthogonal projection, in OP case onto constant functions. Therefore $$A^{-1}= (I-P)+2P=I+P$$ In general if $$A=I -\alpha P=(I-P)+(1-\alpha)P $$ for $\alpha \neq 1,$ then $$A^{-1}=(I-P) +{1 \over 1-\alpha } P\quad (*)$$
For $v$ by applying the Pythagorean theorem twice we get $$\|A^{-1}v\|^2=\|(I-P)v\|^2+{1\over |1-\alpha|^2}\|Pv\|^2\\ 
\le {1\over \min\{1,|1-\alpha |^2\}}[\|(I-P)v\|^2+\|Pv\|^2]\\ =
{1\over \min\{1,|1-\alpha |^2\}}\,\|v\|^2 $$ Therefore $$\|A^{-1}\|\le {1\over \min\{1,|1-\alpha |\}}$$
By $(*)$ the norm is attained either on the range of $P$ or on the range of $I-P, $ depending which number $1$ or $|1-\alpha |$ is smaller.